# Mocking only a single method on an object

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I'm familiar with other mocking libraries in other languages such as Mockito in Java, but Python's `mock` library confuses the life out of me.

I have the following class which I would like to test.

```
class MyClassUnderTest(object):

    def submethod(self, *args):
       do_dangerous_things()

    def main_method(self):
       self.submethod("Nothing.")
```

In my tests, I'd like to make sure that the `submethod` was called when `main_method` was executed and that it was called with the right arguments. I don't want `submethod` to run, as it does dangerous things.

I'm entirely unsure as to how to get started with this. Mock's documentation is incredibly hard to understand and I'm not sure what to even mock or how to mock it.

How can I mock the `submethod` function, while leaving the functionality in `main_method` alone?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `mock.patch.object`

```
with mock.patch.object(MyClassUnderTest, "submethod") as submethod_mocked:
    submethod_mocked.return_value = 13
    MyClassUnderTest().main_method()
    submethod_mocked.assert_called_once_with(user_id, 100, self.context,
                                             self.account_type)
```

Here is small description

```
 patch.object(target, attribute, new=DEFAULT, 
              spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, 
              autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)
```

> patch the named member (attribute) on an object (target) with a mock object.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I've been having a difficult time understanding all of the different `patch` methods and how to use them.